# Matching implementations to parts of the pattern

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

While trying to understand the MVVM pattern I came across [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/kreekman/techdays-2010-understanding-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern) linked from the [MVVM Light Toolkit website](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/).

In [TechDays 2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/kreekman/techdays-2010-understanding-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern) - Laurent Bugnion states the WPF/Silverlight both use MVVM pattern for their structure. Can someone please clarify which components in WPF/SL (*which Bugnion named specifically and are listed below*) are the Model, ViewModel, and View?

#### These are the three items he stated as being a part of the MVVM pattern:

1. Code
2. Dependency Properties
3. Control Templates (*Data Templates?*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the first to admit that this is a little bit stretched ;) but let me clarify. The statement was made to illustrate that MVVM is a very natural pattern in SL/WPF (and all other frameworks that use XAML and databinding). In the example, I was talking about the separation of concerns between the control's code (not referring to "code" in general, but specifically to a control's code, for example a Button class) and its template. In this illustration, the code acts like a ViewModel, i.e. it drives the view. The template is more obviously the View. And the glue between those is the databinding which is enabled through Dependency Properties.

When I say it is a bit of a stretch, we can see that there is no Model in this analogy. Also, the mechanism binding a control's view to its viewmodel (code) is a little more complex than just DPs and bindings. There are also naming conventions added to that.

In retrospect, I guess I could have been clearer, and I pushed this analogy a bit too far. I guess the main point I would like you to take from this is: In SL/WPF, code and view are loosely coupled through databinding. This is true for basic controls, and you can also structure your application in a loosely coupled manner, with the help of databindings.

I hope it makes a little more sense now ;)

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: Nice of you to drop by, clarify and handle question this way

Answer (score 1):

I haven't watched the video. Definitely the control templates and data templates are your views. The dependency properties are really also part of your view, but can be bound to data in a class which serves as a model for the view, i.e. the view-model. The "code" he's referring to must be the business logic which is your model.

I would think of it as three objects. You have a view object, like a TextBox control which has styling applied to it in the form of other view objects that comprise the templates. The TextBox also has dependency properties which are objects that can bind (synchronize) a value on the TextBox to a value on another object. That object is the DataContext of the TextBox, which is your view-model object. The view-model object can be thought of as an adapter for a model to support the specific needs of the view.

Answer (score 1):

```
The Model represents the data and business logic. It should represent your business
```

(domain) and it should not be aware by anyway of your UI.

```
The View this is the UI – the bridge between your software and its users. Normally
```

the View is only aware of the ViewModel but there might be cases in which it may make 
sense to expose the Model directly to it. So your XAML for UI like Grid, Button, 
DataTemplate,Style, control Template etc can be found here.

```
The ViewModel: this is the way you connect your model to a specific View. See it has
```

code that massages your Models in a way that the View can consume. The ViewModel should be 
View agnostic as the Model should. So the communication between View and ViewModel is 
purely based on DataBinding. When you are dealing with MVVM pattern the use Dependency 
property will be bare minimum. for example when you are creating any Custom control at 
that time you have to use the Dependency property for the supporting the binding.

Comment: So the `ViewModel` is synonymous with the controller as in MVC?

Answer (score 1):

> three items he stated as being a part of the MVVM pattern

There is a flaw in this. These things are not parts of MVVM; they enable MVVM. Parts of MVVM are Model, View and ViewModel. To call 'code' a part of MVVM or to call it a part of the ViewModel is oversimplifying and useless.

There is code in the Listbox control; it wouldn't function if there weren't.

Of course, code in the View is frowned upon while others say it is very well possible.

When trying to understand MVVM focus on the responsibilities of the Model, ViewModel and View and do not worry too much about code, dependency properties and Control Templates. You cannot map these to MVVM.